# find_one() finds duplicates that are not there

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to copy a remote mongodb atlas server to a local one. I do this by a python script which also checks if the record is already there. I see that eventhough the local database is empty my script find duplicates, which are not in the remote mongodb atlas (at least i cannot find them). I am not so experienced with mongodb and pymongo but I connot see what I am doing wrong. Sometimes Find_one() finds exactly the same record as before (all the fields are the same even the _id) ?

I removed the collection completely from my local server and tried again, but still the same result.

```py
UserscollectionRemote = dbRemote['users']
UserscollectionNew = dbNew['users']

LogcollectionRemote = dbRemote['events']
LogcollectionNew = dbNew['events']

UsersOrg = UserscollectionRemote.find()

for document in UsersOrg:   # loop over all users

   print(document)

   if UserscollectionNew.find_one({'owner_id': document["owner_id"]}) is None:  # check if already there
        UserscollectionNew.insert_one(document)

   UserlogsOrg = LogcollectionRemote.find({'owner_id': document["owner_id"]})  # get all logs from this user

   for doc in UserlogsOrg:
         try:
             if LogcollectionNew.find_one({'date': doc["date"]}) is None: # there was no entry yet with this date
                 LogcollectionNew.insert_one(doc)
             else:
                 print("duplicate");
                 print (doc);
         except:
             print("an error occured finding the document");
             print(doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the second for loop inside the first; that could be trouble.

On a separate note, you should investigate mongodump and mongorestore for copying collections; unless you need to be doing it in code, these tools are better suited for your use case.

Comment: Why should a loop inside a loop give any problems ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about mongodump , for now mongodump would be ok, but later on I want to skip certain records so I need to do it with a python script.

Comment: In your example it is perfectly feasible you will see duplicates because what is there to stop there being multiple items with the same owner_id or the same date? Unless you have enforced this through unique indexes, it is always a possibility.  Why do a find_one anyway; what's wrong with just doing the insert_one for each document?

Comment: The date is actualy epoch time so time and date in the 1/10sec accurate. Making an entry with the same user and time/date seems almost impossible to me.   If I use insert_one and I run the script next week again I have duplicates in my local database ?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "duplicates". If you want to copy the data, then just copy them in with inserts and without checking. If there's specific duplicates you want to avoid, create a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on the collection.

Comment: Yes I think I will use inserts and if it makes doubles I can always delete all records in my destination dB before running the script.